# google chrome extension browserAction.onClicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i can't figure out how to make it work. My script works by itself. but doesn't work with background.js.  I want my google extension to work only if the user clicks on it's icon, so I have created the file background.js and putted the code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "change_content.js"});
});
```

my manifest.json here:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Name",
  "description": "change content.",
  "version": "3.0",


  "browser_action": {

    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["change_content.js"]
    }
  ],


    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/*"
]

}
```

and here is the change_content.js:

```
var oldSource = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = changeContent(oldSource);
function changeContent(source){
.....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are having the issue where `change_content.js` is executing before you press the button is because thats how content scripts work. If you include a content script in your `manifest.json` it will load and execute that script. Try removing the `"content_scripts"` section from the manifest and you should see it work as it should.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!! It solved my problem, that I couldn't solve almost a week. I pooorly understand how the scheme worked, but now I"m so glad!!!! :) Thank you @1337holiday

Answer (score -2):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "change_content.js"});
});
```

I've got a feeling the error lies in you using "null" as it might be searching for a tab with the tabId - null, you should try doing this instead?

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "change_content.js"});
```

Comment: `null` defaults to the active tab of the current window. Omitting the argument is equivalent to using `null`, see the docs for [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query).

Comment: you should read the API, it clearly says its an optional parameter as @RobW stated